# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable, using the Page Object Framework with Selenium/Appium

Tags: python, ios, selenium, appium

Running the following PyUnit test:

```
import unittest #imports unit test/ability to run as pyunit test
from page_objects.webdriver_wrapper import webdriver_wrapper
from page_objects.home import home
from page_objects.inbook import inbook
from page_objects.myebooks import myebooks
from page_objects.login import login
import time

class regression(unittest.TestCase):

    def regression(self, webd_wrap):
        page_login = login(webd_wrap)
        page_login.secure_login()


    def test_regression(self): #running x as a unit test
        for browser in webdriver_wrapper().setUp():
            self.regression(webdriver_wrapper(browser))


print "Module Complete", __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: test_regression (mobile_testing.regression_test.regression)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Zola/Documents/workspace/com.zolamobile.eviltest/mobile_testing/regression_test.py", line 24, in test_regression
    for setUp in webdriver_wrapper().setUp():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

webdriver_wrapper is a library module that includes the setUp to run on this unittest on an iOS device. setUp looks like this:

```
def setUp(self):
        # set up appium
        success = True
        app = "com.zolabooks.zolareader"
        app = os.path.abspath(app)
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities={
                'browserName': 'iOS',
                'platform': 'Mac',
                'version': '6.1',
                'ipa': app
            })
        self._values = []
```

I am trying to get this to work using the Page Object Model framework, so that the elements on pages can be abstracted.

EDIT: This is working code for selenium using browsers instead of iOS:

```
def test_addtolist_notsignedin_modal(self): #running x as a unit test
        for browser in webdriver_wrapper._browsers:
            self.add_to_list_notsignedin_modal_test(webdriver_wrapper(browser))
```

Where _browsers is defined as:

```
_browsers = ["chrome", "firefox"]

def open_chrome(self):
        self._driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Jay/Downloads/chromedriver')
        self._driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self._driver, 10)

    def open_firefox(self):
        self._driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self._driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self._driver, 10)
```

Comment: Isn't setup supposed to return something ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate over the return value from your `setUp()` method:

```
for browser in webdriver_wrapper().setUp():
```

(The error message says `for setUp in webdriver_wrapper().setUp():`... don't know why the difference. Perhaps the code you pasted is different from the code you're actually running. But the cause is the same regardless.)

The problem is `setUp()` doesn't return anything, which means it returns `None`. `None`, as the error message says, is not iterable.

It's unclear to me exactly what `setUp()` should be returning. A list or an iterator, obviously, but of what? Browsers? Setups? I don't see anything of that sort.

Comment: In the working example, `_browsers` opens chrome and firefox. In the broken example, setUp is supposed to open the application.

Comment: OK... well, that code is totally different from the code you're asking about... obviously it doesn't work for what you're trying to do, or you'd be using it. What is the purpose of posting it?

Comment: Because it is conceptually similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setUp` function returns nothing (ie: None) and then you write:

```
for browser in webdriver_wrapper().setUp():
```

which is supposed to iterate through the result of `setUp`... One cannot iterate through `None`. At least return the empty list.